Is there a way to watch content on YouTube while logged in without influencing future recommendations?
On YouTube, I sometimes watch political videos, but typically, I do not.
Is it possible to watch them from time to time without YouTube starting to recommend political content to me?
Does anyone have a way to do this short of accessing political content with a separate account?
I don't want to watch while completely logged out of my account because YouTube does a good job of curating content that I'm interested in and don't find objectionable.

There are two ways to do this: delete the history you want or turn off (and on) watch history while watching those videos:

If you delete some or all of your watch history, YouTube won’t base future video recommendations on that content. Any videos that you watch while history is turned off won't show up in your history.

You can do so on myactivity.google.com. See the full article for more details: View, delete, or turn on or off watch history.

The links are useful, thanks but I tried this and YT seems not to honour my wishes. I cleared my history and whist initially, nothing was presented in my feed, after a short while, YT caught up with my account and I got hit with massive amounts of content in which I have no interest including videos that I had already seen and maried as such. Seems |YT has no interest in respecting a users wishes - only its advertisers.
